# Construct equation with words.. construct words with equations

Tags: word-problem, almost-everywhere

When I am given a word problem I could frame a statement/equation depending on the words given. But when I am given equations, then is it possible to frame words/sentences depending on the elements of the given equation?

What is it that I will be doing in the real-time math? Word Problems or Equations that are given?

What I am saying is, the word problems are long form of writing equations. And the equations are the short form of writing words-problem. Every problem can be either in words or equations. Correct?

Comment: This is a quite broad question. What do you mean by the question "What is it that I will be doing in the real-time math? " ? What is real-time math?

Comment: Real-time math are word problems like: A climber is on hike. After 2 hours he is at an altitude of 400 ft. After 6 hours he is at an altitude of 700 ft. What is the average rate of change?

Comment: Okay, how is that different from a normal word problem?

Comment: @Matti P. There is no difference. What I am trying to understand is that the problems/equations given in a math textbook is just a short notation of word problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You absolutely can "invent" some real-world context for every Math equation, thus formulating the problem with words.

For example $x-3=5$ can be posed as "Paul gave me some money yesterday. I've spent $€3$ but still have $€5$. How much should I give him back when I see him again?"

$x=x_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2}at^2$ can be interpreted as "there's a constant force $a$ acting on an object that, when I started measuring was at position $x_0$ and was moving at speed $v_0$. Where is it after $t$ seconds?

In reality, every physics equation is just a case of a "math problem turned into words" or vice-versa